# Angular 2 + HTML5 Video Loading / Rendering

Tags: html, angular, video

I have an Angular 2 application using the HashLocation strategy with 3 videos within a component.

When the component loads, the 2 short videos (15 seconds) load, but the longer video (60 seconds) does not. I can right click & select "Open video in new tab" and the video plays fine in the new tab. Since my component loads so quickly, could this be a rendering problem with the HTML5 video tag not loading the MP4 file?

I'm stumped and have not found any similar problems with Angular 2 + HTML5 Video tag. All help & brainstorming is appreciated.

I've already looked into [videogular2](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2) but it's still in alpha.